# How to print the object json when JsonProperty is different of attribute?

Tags: java, json, jackson

If I have any class, for example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

class Person {

    @JsonProperty("alternativeName")
    private String name;
}
```

I have a instance of A with `name = "test"`

I would like to have in log:

```
Object Person(alternativeName=test, ... [other JsonProperty..])
```

How to get that object with the JsonProperty instead the attributes? Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Did you try `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(person);`?

Comment: @HelloWorld123456789 your code is ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it shows in your log depends on the `toString()` method. It usually includes the name of the attribute and does not handle `@JsonProperty` annotations. You have two ways of doing this:

1. Change `toString()` implementation so that it prints `alternativeName` instead of `name`. The downside of this is that you will then need to adapt two `String`s if you want to change `alternativeName` to anything else.
2. Use `ObjectMapper` `writeValueAsString()` method in your log statement. This will take `@JsonProperty` into consideration but it will log `Person` as JSON and not as a regular POJO (as you depicted in your example).

Now you need to compromise and select what you consider being the best approach.